# Problems installing any type of Windows

Tags: windows, hard-drive, 64-bit, installation

When trying to install Windows 7 x64 on a new PC with a formatted hard drive I get the following error when extracting files:

> Windows cannot install required files.
>   The file may be corrupt or missing.
>   Make sure all files required for
>   installation are available, and
>   restart the installation. Error code:
>   **0x80070570**

I've googled for the error and came up with a few tips about taking out one of the RAM sticks but that has not solved anything. The same error comes up when trying to install using a pre-RTM release of Windows 7 which I know is working.

**Edit**: I tried using a DVD with Windows 7 x86 on it (both the image and the DVD are fine, I've checked them before), without any luck.

I've also tried installing Windows XP SP3, as Noam Gal suggested. The installation gets stuck at checking the computer hardware (the first step after inserting the CD).

This has happened before, when I tried to install an OS on my old PC. The connection between the 2 PCs is the **hard drive**; it's the same one. I'm convinced it is the culprit, but I have no idea what to do. How can I format it so that this behavior stops? The hard drive is physically ok, it works without any problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Errors during a clean OS install are **almost always hardware problems**. Seriously!

Some ideas:

1. Make a [memtest86 bootable cd](http://www.memtest.org/) and running a memory test for a few hours. This will ensure it's not faulty memory.
2. Run [Prime95](http://www.mersenne.org/freesoft/) in torture test mode overnight to make sure it's not a heat / stability / cpu issue.
3. Possible is bad installation media (DVD) or a faulty DVD drive. You could try [installing win7 from a USB key](http://www.maximumpc.com/article/howtos/how_to_install_windows_7_beta_a_usb_key) -- copying all the Win7 install files to a large USB stick, make it bootable, and try that as well.

Comment: The problem is the computer's brand new. I'm leaning towards hardware related myself, but I think the hard drive is responsible. I've had problems installing XP in the past, but Vista worked and I assumed the problems had gone away.

Comment: It was a RAM problem after all. I managed to install Windows 7 after countless attempts. When it crashed, Windows decided to perform some hardware tests; the result of those tests was RAM failure.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like this error is associated with a corrupt DVD or installation media. If you burned the DVD yourself, try burning it again at the slowest speed possible.

There also could be a problem with the DVD reader. If you can, try extracting the .iso to a removable hard drive and install it from that. This way you can avoid errors that come with such a temperamental medium, such as DVDs and their readers. Check out [this guide](http://www.blogsdna.com/2016/how-to-install-windows-7-from-usb-drive-without-windows-7-iso-dvd.htm) from BlogsDNA for an in-depth guide on how to do this.

If you are still getting the error, it is possible that the .iso file is corrupt. Try downloading it agin (if you can). Make sure you are getting it from a reliable source (such as straight from Microsoft).

Comment: As I said in my question, the same thing is happening with an older installation DVD that I know works (I've actually used that one before).

Comment: See me recent edit: "There also could be a problem with the DVD reader..."

Comment: I never thought of the DVD drive. I'll try installing from an USB stick, as Jeff suggested. I did burn the DVD myself, but this wouldn't be the first time, and I've never had problems before. But I have had problems with MSDN AA iso images before. The image I'm using is straight from the Microsoft servers.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue on a brand new computer. Tried changing the dvd, re-burning it, changing the dvd drive.. Always got the same problem. I also tried installing from usb (Formatted my ipod for it), but never got it to boot from it (I tried following all the instructions on the web)
At the end, I installed XP on the machine, just to prove to myself the drive was functioning, and the hard drive was not broken. The XP installed just fine. I then  decided to give the 7x64 another try, and it just worked.
Have no idea why it happened, but at the end I got a working 7x64 on the new pc.
Hope this tip works for you as well.

Comment: I really hope I don't have to jump through so many hoops just to install Windows 7.

Comment: Well, I don't think it's that bad - instead of having to switch dvd reader/mobo/memory/hard drive, you just click through an xp install, and then re boot to the 7x64 install.
It shouldn't take that long. And hopefully it'll work :-)

Comment: I wasn't able to install XP either. I've added more info in my question just to let everybody know what I've tried up to now.